# PrimeNg - Data Table Selection Values with Nested Components

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a `p-dataTable` with nested `p-dropdown` components.  On selection of a row, how can I get the selected values of the row?  In the selection callback I receive the array backing each dropdown, and not the selection itself.

[image]

```
<p-dataTable [value]="affiliates" sortField="name" dataKey="id"  selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [rows]="15" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="10">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name" sortable="true" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search" filterMatchMode="contains"></p-column>    
    <p-column field="package" header="Packages">
        <ng-template let-affiliate="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <p-dropdown [options]="affiliate.packages" dataKey="label"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="country" header="Countries">
        <ng-template let-affiliate="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <p-dropdown [options]="affiliate.countries" dataKey="label"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="device" header="Devices">
        <ng-template let-affiliate="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <p-dropdown [options]="affiliate.devices" dataKey="label"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column header="Actions">

    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the row data using the `event.data` property in the callback event.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="affiliates" sortField="name" dataKey="id"  selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [rows]="15" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="10">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name" sortable="true" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search" filterMatchMode="contains"></p-column>    
    <p-column field="package" header="Packages">
        <ng-template let-affiliate="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="name.selectedPackage" [options]="affiliate.packages" dataKey="label"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="country" header="Countries">
        <ng-template let-affiliate="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="country.selectedCountry"
             [options]="affiliate.countries" dataKey="label"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="device" header="Devices">
        <ng-template let-affiliate="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="device.selectedDevice"
             [options]="affiliate.devices" dataKey="label"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column header="Actions">

    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Call back event will look as

```
onRowSelect(event){
    this.selectedData=event.data
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/DAPVDkfM4dyyIDJdAKve?p=preview)**